# Stranded wire was cut... Connecting it back together, with solid wire... Is this safe and possible?

Tags: ac, connector, wire, plug

I have this connector for a monitor and the wires were cut. So now I’m trying to put them back together with electrical tape.

I stripped the stranded wires and connected it to a short solid wire, then connected the other end of the solid wire to the other stranded wire. Is this possible and SAFE? I’m afraid to test it out. I’m only using electrical tape; I have no soldering iron. Should I just connect the two stranded wires as is, without using a short solid wire as a middle man? Any advice would be very much appreciated.

[image: I did it, sort of like this. but more tightly wrapped around the solid wire. The same for the other end.]

[image: This is the connector. Its for an Acer Monitor.]

Comment: What kind of connector are we dealing with here?

Comment: I don’t see the point of the solid wire.

Comment: how does the picture relate to your question?

Comment: someone asked for the type of cable.

Comment: where is it cut?

Comment: This is one of those questions I don't answer on the principle of "If you have to ask, you should not be playing with it!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's safe. There is no safety issue with doing what you want. If your very paranoid, you could use heat shrink instead.

<strike>But it may not work. Some of these logic signals may not like being disturbed with mismatched lengths or resistance.  You can try it and if it works, great. But you may try aftermarket sources like eBay for a replacement cables. Instead of soldering a random amount of cables.</strike>

It's a power cable? There is no issue honestly. Though to be fair, modular power cables are cheap. You should replace it if possible.

Comment: yes it is a power cable for the monitor. i'll try it thank you for the response

Comment: That said, you can get a new cable for like a dollar. Unless it's a built in cable, which some monitors have. Of you can unplug it at both ends, then just buy a new one.

Comment: Use the special connectors suitable for both stranded and soldid. No twisting, no tape, no screws. See my answer

Answer (score 6):

That's neither safe nor robust. The solid wire could break after being flexed, and the tape won't reliably hold it together.

Perhaps more importantly, simply twisting the wires together without solder or the pressure of a crimp or screw terminal will not give a low-resistance, gas-tight joint. The resistance will likely increase over time as the conductors oxidize. The power supply will draw more and more current to compensate for the voltage drop over that resistance. \$P=I^2R\$ and that heat can either directly start a fire or melt the insulation leading to a short circuit.

Buy a new cable, they're incredibly common and cheap.

Comment: What makes it unsafe? Electrical tape has been used for decades.

Comment: And solid wire is used for many purposes. It's a computer monitor, not exactly a high movement prone item.

Comment: i just wanted to try to fix it, and see if it works. if it doesn't i'll just buy a new cable. i did this for the purpose of learning a little something.

Comment: It will work though

Comment: It actually worked, thanks. but sadly the monitor display itself is broken. haven't used this monitor in more than 5 years, just wanted to test it out. but the monitor is broken sad

Answer (score 2):

It is safe but it is not a very robust solution. If, for some reason, you cannot buy a new cable (e.g. urgent emergency repair), it is far more robust to use some low cost screw connectors like these:

[image]

They are easily separated using a stanley knife or a strong cutter. Use three of those to join the three stranded wires inside your cable. If you are not in a critical environment, they may suffice. For extra insulation and safety, wrap the assembly in electrical tape and you'll have a fairly strong connection.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You could use this kind of connector. Suitable for both stranded and solid.
It is safe and simple to apply